# How to read Multi message stream, uncompressed Protobuf files using Elephant-Bird?

Tags: apache-pig, protocol-buffers, elephantbird

I have a bunch of uncompressed protobuf binary log files (*.binlog). In additional to being uncompressed, each file/stream contains a variable number of messages.

I'm trying to load these files into HDFS and query them using Pig.

My question is:

Is it possible to read the uncompressed files using Elephant-Bird at all? I have also tried to read bzip2 encoded files but my attempts so far 
gives me the `Failed to read from file` error

I'm trying

```
register '/all-libraries/*.jar';
raw_data = load 'file.binlog' using com.twitter.elephantbird.pig.load.ProtobufPigLoader('my_package.My_proto_Class');
```

The load function returns without error but when I say

```
value = foreach raw_data generate field1; //doesn't throw error
dump value //throws error
```

### Pig Stack Trace

ERROR 1066: Unable to open iterator for alias value

org.apache.pig.impl.logicalLayer.FrontendException: ERROR 1066: Unable to open iterator for alias person_phone_numbers
    at org.apache.pig.PigServer.openIterator(PigServer.java:892)
    at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.processDump(GruntParser.java:774)
    at org.apache.pig.tools.pigscript.parser.PigScriptParser.parse(PigScriptParser.java:372)
    at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.parseStopOnError(GruntParser.java:198)
    at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.parseStopOnError(GruntParser.java:173)
    at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt.run(Grunt.java:69)
    at org.apache.pig.Main.run(Main.java:541)
    at org.apache.pig.Main.main(Main.java:156)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:221)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:136)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Job terminated with anomalous status FAILED
    at org.apache.pig.PigServer.openIterator(PigServer.java:884)
    ... 13 more

NAy anybody give a hint if this is possible at all? How can I direct `ProtobufPigLoader` to read the message length before reading the message?

Comment: Are you able to dump raw_data? -- Have you tried running this code with trivial input?